# Calculate AIC or Anova from an RJags model

Tags: anova, multiple-regression, aic, model-comparison, jags

I am fitting multivariate linear regressions with RJags (I have to do it with an mcmc because I'm taking all errors into account).

I want to know between two polynomials **which one fits better my data**. Here is the RJags code I am using for the simpler model (model1), with some arbitrary data. For model2 the code is the same, just changing the polynomial *y.hat* to a two degree polynomial:

```
modelFile1 = "model1.txt"
modelString1 = "
model {
# Likelihood:
for (i in 1:N) {
y[i] ~ dnorm(y.hat[i], tauy[i])
y.hat[i] <- b[1] + b[2]*x.hat[i] + b[3]*z.hat[i] 

x.hat[i] ~ dnorm(x[i], taux[i])
z.hat[i] ~ dnorm(z[i], tauz[i])

taux[i] <- 1/pow(sdx[i],2)
tauy[i] <- 1/pow(sdy[i],2)
tauz[i] <- 1/pow(sdz[i],2)
}

for(j in 1:3) {b[j]~dunif(-2,2)}

}
"
writeLines(modelString,con=modelFile)


#Data

 ind <- data.frame(A = c(2.428, 2.601, 2.749, 2.553, 2.753, 2.421, 2.579, 2.415, 2.407, 2.509),
                  B = c(0.95, 0.99, 1.05, 1.00, 1.04, 0.96, 1.01, 0.95, 0.95, 1.01),
                  C = c(-0.04, -0.09, 0.01, 0.04, -0.15, 0.11, -0.17, -0.12, -0.13, 0.17),
                  eA=runif(10, 0, 0.5), eB=runif(10,0,0.5), eC=runif(10,0,0.2))

ml.data <- list(x=ind$A,
                        y=ind$B,
                z=ind$C,
                        sdy=ind$eA,
                sdx=ind$eB,
                        sdz=ind$eC,
                N=nrow(ind))

ml.par1 <- c("b")

ml.mod1 <- jags.model(modelFile1,data=ml.data, n.chains=10, n.adapt=1000)

update(ml.mod1, n.iter = 1000)

mcmc.out1 <- coda.samples(ml.mod1, var=ml.par1, n.iter=10000)

#summary of the posterior distributions of the parameters
summary(mcmc.out1)
```

So I would like to compare *mcmc.out1* and *mcmc.out2*.
I know that RJags has the **DIC** implemented and that I can accept the first model if the DIC is negative and reverse. However I am not so convinced of the results because:

1. I have read about DIC and it seems not to be as robust as AIC or ANOVA in model selection
2. MCMC is an iterative process and the DIC is not giving me always the same result for the same set of data (sometimes it's positive, sometimes it's negative...)... Too ambiguous, and **I need more robustness**.

**Is there a better way I can compare the rjags outputs of both models? 
How can I calculate the AIC or ANOVA as it is done in *lm*?** (rjags doesn't give the residuals so I don't know how to achieve this...)